# Visual Basic error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Im getting an error at line 15, 'end of statement expected'

What am I doing wrong? Even the class whiz kid says this should work, as is:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
    Dim states() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("USStates.txt")  ' makes array
    Dim data = From state In states
    Let line = state.Split(","c)
    Let Name = line(0)
    Let stateAb = line(1)
    Let area = CInt(line(2))
    Let census = CDbl(line(3))
    Order By Name Ascending
    ' query
    Select name,stateAb,area,census
```

*GETTING ERROR HERE***

```
    dgvOut.DataSource = data.ToList
    dgvOut.CurrentCell = Nothing
    dgvOut.Columns("Name").HeaderText = "State Name"
    dgvOut.Columns("ststeAb").HeaderText = "Abbreviation"
    dgvOut.Columns("area").HeaderText = "Area In Sq. Miles"
    dgvOut.Columns("census").HeaderText = "Population"
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Which version of VB/Visual Studio/.NET Framework?

Comment: where is the rest of the code?

Comment: @asawyer are you an expert in LINQ? Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Not sure what your asking here, but if the OP is taking a class as implied in the question, the best place to ask for help is with the teacher, not the internet.

Comment: @asawyer My apologies, I assumed your advise was sarcastic.

Comment: This is an online course, and the teacher takes far too long to answer a simple email.  AND I'm using 2012 express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `' query` - you can't put a comment there.

Comment: Thanks. The query wont run with comments in it, I was told tonight

Answer (score 1):

Try it with line continuations:

```
Dim data = From state In states _
Let line = state.Split(","c) _
Let Name = line(0) _
Let stateAb = line(1) _
Let area = CInt(line(2)) _
Let census = CDbl(line(3)) _
Order By Name Ascending _
Select name, stateAb, area, census
```